# Smallest number in 2d array not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the smallest number in the array.
When i execute this code, it shows "23" as smallest.
I am not able to find the mistake, can anyone help me out?

Here is the code to find the smallest number in 2d array which i tried.
When i execute this code, it shows "23" as smallest.
I am not able to find the mistake.

```
public class arraymin {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr1[][]=new int[][]{{23,32,10,44},{44,33,22,11}};
        int minvalue=arr1[0][0];
        for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<arr1.length;j++)
            {
                if(arr1[i][j]<minvalue)
                {
                   minvalue= arr1[i][j];
                }
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("Min Value is: "+minvalue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You inner loop should be

```
for(int j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++)
```

since the number of columns is different than the number of rows.

And the full code:

```
public class arraymin {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int arr1[][]=new int[][]{{23,32,10,44},{44,33,22,11}};
    int minvalue=arr1[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i][j]<minvalue)
            {
               minvalue= arr1[i][j];
            }
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("Min Value is: "+minvalue);
  }
}
```

Your current code only checks the first two columns in each row, so out of 23,32,44 and 33, 23 is the smallest number.

Answer (score 2):

In your inner loop, you use:

```
for(int j=0;j<arr1.length;j++)
```

but those arrays are longer, so it will only look at the first two elements of those arrays, making 23 indeed the smallest.

Change the above to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 2. for loop to

```
for(int j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++)
```

Otherwise you won't cover all elements of the inner array.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is only going up to arr1.length for both dimensions. The inner loop should go up to arr1[i].length.

Answer (score 0):

When you write arr1.length in 2nd for loop it returns 2 as there are 2 rows in the array.So you need to change the condition to :

```
for(int j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++)
```

such that it can traverse through all the coloumns(4 coloumns).

Try this code :

```
public class arraymin {
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int arr1[][]=new int[][]{{23,32,10,44},{44,33,22,11}};
    int minvalue=arr1[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++)    //change in this line
        {
            if(arr1[i][j]<minvalue)
            {
               minvalue= arr1[i][j];
            }
        } 
    }
     System.out.println("Min Value is: "+minvalue);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't just change code, explain what you changed, why you changed it and what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your inner loop condition to *arr1[i].length*, since *arr1.length* returns only no. of rows so your program will once traverse through 2x2 matrix instead of 2x4. and 23 is the smallest number among 23,32 | 44, 33 so it's returning 23.

```
**for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i][j]<minvalue)
            {
               minvalue= arr1[i][j];
            }
        } 
    }**
```